# Get Planner Data "assigned to" users using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

When I use this API

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/planner/plans/{Palnid}/tasks
```

I fetch all tasks in plan, and as mention in documentation the users are assigned to task will by in `assignmentsProperty` but the data in `assignmentsProperty` is created by user not assigned to user

How to get "Assigned to" users or users id for tasks?

Answer (score 0):

I found the "Assigned To" User id
it's in `assignmentsProperty` Key not value
[image: assignmentsProperty Tag]